# Creating a JButton with the click of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, software-design

I am working on a project where I need to click a button to make another button. Eventually, I would l like to have more control over the new button positioning and being able to create new ones multiple times, but for now...I am looking to just make one JButton Create another JButton.

With the code below, my goal is to have the White B1 create a Red B3 button. I also want the Blue B2 button to create a Green B4 buttion.

Eventually, I also want the B3 and B4 (buttons generated from buttons) to have the user be able to click those and make it disappear.

Neither button seems to do anything and I can't figure out why. I have 3 class files. Any idea where I may be going wrong?

**Window.Java**

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //frame creation
    JFrame frame = new MainFrame("Button Create Button Test");

    //frame size
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

**DetailsPanel.Java**

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DetailsPanel extends JPanel {
    public DetailsPanel() {
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 400;
        setPreferredSize(size);

        ///Buttons

        JButton button1 = new JButton("B1");
        button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (72, 73));
        button1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        button1.setBorderPainted(true);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("B2");
        button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (72, 73));
        button2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        button2.setBorderPainted(true);


        setLayout (new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        /// Layout ///
        /// Row 1 ///

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

        gc.weightx = 0.5;
        gc.weighty = 0.5;

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;

        add(button1, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;

        add(button2, gc);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton button3 = new JButton("B3");
                button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (72, 73));
                button3.setBackground(Color.RED);
                button3.setBorderPainted(true);

                gc.gridx = 1;
                gc.gridy = 3;

                add(button3, gc);
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton button4 = new JButton("B3");
                button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (72, 73));
                button4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                button4.setBorderPainted(true);

                gc.gridx = 1;
                gc.gridy = 4;

                add(button4, gc);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainFrame.Java**

```
    package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private DetailsPanel detailsPanel;

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        // set layout manager
        setLayout (new BorderLayout());

        // Create Swing Component
        detailsPanel = new DetailsPanel();
        detailsPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        // Add swing components to content pane
        Container container = getContentPane();

        container.add(detailsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);



            }       
    }
```

Comment: hmm, why not just pre-create the buttons and just make them visible?

Comment: For what I am looking to do in the end, it wouldn’t work for me. Eventually, I’ll have way more buttons 70+ that all great another button, but you’d only have like 5-10 displayed at a time in smaller panel in the GUI. I also want to make it dynamic. So that if I click B1, then B2 it creates B3 and B4 and displays it in that order. If I click B2 then B1 then it displays B4 and B3 (again in that order visually). B4 left of B3. Hope that makes sense

Comment: *"Hope that makes sense"* And I hope for a flying pony that excretes ice cream. Seems neither of us will get our hopes fulfilled today. **What is the ultimate purpose of all this creation of buttons?** It'd help if the buttons had meaningful names like `processStep7` that would hint to their use.

Comment: In your `Window` class, you don't add any component to the `JFrame`. Are you sure you haven't left some code out by accident? Also the contents of `MainFrame.java` are identical to `DetailsPanel.java`. Is this also an accident?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that! I've updated the codes to reflect the right class info!

Comment: We don't need to know the purpose behind the creation of the buttons. The question asking about how to create buttons by pressing other buttons is fine as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for button B3 to be displayed after clicking button B1, you need to add...

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

after the line...

```
add(button3, gc);
```

in file `DetailsPanel.java`.
Similarly for button B2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger a repaint of your layout manager after adding the button.

After

```
  add(button3, gc);
```

add

```
invalidate();
validate();
```

see Swing documentation and javadoc of invalidate() and validate() for details.

Comment: FYI `revalidate` will call both and is easier to type ... because I'm lazy ;)

Comment: Thanks for the above comments. I did some more research on the revalidate and repaint, and it seems like this will what I need to implement, but I am not sure I figured out the way to do this. I'm not sure if it is the frame, panel, or something else that needs to be repainted. I tried putting this within the button 1 and button 2 action events, but didn't have any luck.